# Chrome serial port communication

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome-extension, serial-port, communication

I'm trying to connect a lab equipment via a serial port to a computer to communicate with it. My application is a web based one, so I use Chrome browser. I want to get a data from MYSQL database and send it to the lab equipment and the response from the equipment to the database. Without using a native software, can I do this by using the chrome.serial api and a Chrome extension? Or is there any good other way to do it without using a native software?

Comment: Extensions can't use chrome.serial, only the deprecated [chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) can.

Comment: Chrome apps will not be continued any more. Isn't it?